# jQuery loop for element and print them

Tags: jquery

I have html like this:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li class="sub1">
        <a>Value1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub1">
        <a>Value2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
    <li class="sub1">
        <a>Value3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub1">
        <a>Value4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
...
```

As you can see there are "UL" with same class and "LI" with the same class. What I need just to loop through every "UL" and every "LI" and print out element "A" value one by one.
The problem with my code that it collect all the matches in one. How to loop and print out separate line by line ?

MY code:

```
$('.container').each(function(i){
   $('.sub1').each(function(a){
        console.log($('a').text());
   });
});
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Please mention that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `print`/`console.log` each `a` tag on each line, you have to use `$(this).find('a').text()`

`this` is the current `.sub1` of the iteration. Then `.find` the `a` and get the text.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sub1').each(function(a) {
    console.log($(this).find('a').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to loop starting from `ul` you can:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container').each(function() {
    console.log( "---- CONTAINER ----" );
    $(this).find('.sub1').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).find('a').text());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Happy to help @andys

Comment: Start writing document ready event handlers from `$(document).ready(function() {` as `$(function() {` as the recommended form.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Updated. Thanks

Comment: + for the second example to process the container groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query to select the values.

```
$(".container .sub1 a").each (function (){
  console.log ($(this).text ());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow simple operation:

```js
$(".sub1 a").each(function(el) {
  console.log($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
    <li class="sub1">
        <a>Value1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub1">
        <a>Value2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
    <li class="sub1">
        <a>Value3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub1">
        <a>Value4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ul.container li a` this will select all the `a` which are under `li.sub1` of `ul.container`.

```js
$("ul.container li.sub1 a").each(function(el) {
  console.log($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub1">
    <a>Value4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```